# browser return %7Bhttp_host%D's ip could not found when redirecting to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have client that when try to visit the website his browser return

> %7Bhttp_host%D's ip could not found

I have htaccess with following commands:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^www)*\.
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

what is the problem? the strange thing is that the website is opening fine from my laptop and phone.

Comment: Show the complete request + response headers for their initial request

Comment: A scientific guess: their client does not send the `host` header.

Comment: @zerkms I am trying to let the client send me the header and response, but, meanwhile he is using google chrome and supposing you are correct about your guess the what would be the fix?

Comment: It's unlikely any google chrome even the most ancient version could behave that way.

Comment: What request are they making to start with? HTTP or HTTPS? With or without `www` subdomain? (And what is that second RewriteCond even supposed to achieve?)